# missing variable to complete cell execution

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I hope someone can help me. I've been stuck with this error for a while. I have two `.py` files that I am importing in a jupyter notebook. When running the last cell (see code below) I get a Traceback error I can'f fix.

I think there is some error in my `ch_data_prep.py` file related to variable `df_ch` not correctly passed between files. Is this possible? Any suggestion on how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

**ch_data_prep.py**

```
def seg_data(self):
    seg_startdate = input('Enter start date (yyyy-mm-dd): ')
    seg_finishdate = input('Enter end date (yyyy-mm-dd): ')

    df_ch_seg = df_ch[(df_ch['event_datetime'] > seg_startdate) 
                    & (df_ch['event_datetime'] < seg_finishdate)
              ]

    return df_ch_seg

df_ch_seg = seg_data(df_ch)
```

**ch_db.py**

```
def get_data():
    
    # Some omitted code here to connect to database and get data...
    
    df_ch = pd.DataFrame(result)
    return df_ch

df_ch = get_data()
```

**Jupyter Notebook data_analysis.ipynb**

```
In[1]:  import ch_db
        df_ch = ch_db.get_data()

In[2]:  import ch_data_prep
```

**When I run cell 2, I get this error**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-fbe2d4fceba6> in <module>
----> 1 import ch_data_prep

~/clickstream/ch_data_prep.py in <module>
     34     return df_ch_seg
     35 
---> 36 df_ch_seg = seg_data()

TypeError: seg_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'df_ch'
```

Comment: Your error shows that you called seg_data() without any arguments, but your first code snippet shows an argument passed, so it's unclear what you actually ran.  Also, what is `self`?  Is `seg_data()` part of a class definition?  You should also have all imports done at the beginning of your Jupyter notebook and make calls to imported functions only in that notebook.  Basically, if you want to use an object in another script, you have to import it in that script. That applies to passing objects between your two .py scripts.

Comment: Thank you @AlexK. Actually seg_data() is not part of a class definition, the "self" was an attempt I made after watching a tutorial about Python Classes.. but I understand now it is useless and out of context. In the meanwhile, I simplified the code and merged my first 2 scripts into one module. I am now importing only one module with all custom functions into my Jupyter Notebook. However I am still getting some errors as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67247958/when-importing-a-module-in-jupyter-and-executing-a-function-manually-cell-retur