# When importing a module in jupyter and executing a function manually, cell returns "error module has no attribute"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to collect my main functions in a separate .py module, that I am importing in my Juptyer Notebook. So I can call a function when I need it. I would like to keep this simple, as I am a beginner in Python.

I have 2 main problems:

- When I import the db.py module in my Jupyter notebook, all def functions are executed.

> I read this is normal in Python and it can be prevented by placing `if __name__ == "__main__":` before the functions I want to execute manually. And it seems to work.

- However, if I add the code above, when I run the functions manually, I get this other error
  module 'ch_db' has no attribute 'get_data'

Any suggestion?

**db.py - this is the file where i would like to collect my functions**

```
def main():

    print('Credentials required')

    print('Enter User:')
    pass_user = getpass.getpass()

    print('Enter db pssw:')
    pass_clickhouse = getpass.getpass()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    def get_data():
            # ... some other code to get data from database ...
            df_ch = pd.DataFrame(result)

            return df_ch

    df_ch = get_data()

    def seg_data():
            seg_startdate = input('Enter start date (yyyy-mm-dd): ')
            seg_finishdate = input('Enter end date (yyyy-mm-dd): ')
            df_ch_seg = df_ch[(df_ch['event_datetime'] > seg_startdate) 
                            & (df_ch['event_datetime'] < seg_finishdate)]

            return df_ch_seg

    df_ch_seg = seg_data()
```

**In Jupyter Notebook:**

```
In[1]: import ch_db
In[2]: db.get_data() 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-78c2ac644f6e> in <module>
----> 1 ch_db.get_data()

AttributeError: module 'db' has no attribute 'get_data'
```

Comment: I don't really understand how Jupyter notebook would execute all functions defined in your file. What if the functions need parameters?

Comment: You should move the function definitions (`def` blocks) outside of `if __name__ == "__main__":`. The way you have it written, any module (or notebook) that imports `db.py` will not know anything about those functions.  You define a function, import it (giving you access to that function object) and then call that object with any arguments as necessary.

Comment: Hi @AlexK I think we are almost there to succeed! I edited the code and put it in a new page, so we can keep this other one for future reference for other learners. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67248274/saving-values-to-be-passed-as-argument-in-following-separate-manual-functions-ex