# Saving values to be passed as argument in following separate manual functions execution in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I succeeded in collecting my custom functions in a separate `db.py` file, which I then import into a Jupyter notebook. I am now able to call mu custom functions separately, but I am getting a new error, related to missing arguments.

Please find the updated code below. After executing the `connect()` function, I would like the system to pass the input values to the `get_data()` function. Isn't the system saving somewhere in memory the values I have provided as inputs during the execution of the `connect()` function, so they can be reused when I execute the `get_data()` function?

**ch_db.py - this is the file where i collect my custom functions**

```
import getpass
import pandas as pd

def connect():
    print('Credentials required')
    print('Enter User:')
    pass_user = getpass.getpass()
    print('Enter db pssw:')
    pass_clickhouse = getpass.getpass()
    date_var = input('Enter date range yyyy-mm-dd: ')
    return pass_user, pass_clickhouse, date_var
    pass_user, pass_clickhouse, date_var = ch_db.connect()

def get_data(pass_user, pass_clickhouse, date_var):
    # ... some other code to get data from database ...
    df_ch = pd.DataFrame(result)
    return df_ch
    df_ch = get_data()

def seg_data():
    seg_startdate = input('Enter start date (yyyy-mm-dd): ')
    seg_finishdate = input('Enter end date (yyyy-mm-dd): ')
    df_ch_seg = df_ch[(df_ch['event_datetime'] > seg_startdate) 
                & (df_ch['event_datetime'] < seg_finishdate)]
    return df_ch_seg
    df_ch_seg = seg_data()
```

**In Jupyter Notebook:**

```
In[1]: import ch_db
In[2]: ch_db.connect()
       Credentials required
       Enter User:
       ········
       Enter Clickhouse pssw:
       ········
       Enter date range yyyy-mm-dd: 2021-04-22

In[3]: ch_db.get_data()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-78c2ac644f6e> in <module>
----> 1 ch_db.get_data()

TypeError: get_data() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'pass_user', 'pass_clickhouse', and 'date_var'
```

Comment: Your `connect()` function returns three values.  You should assign those returned values to three variables (e.g., `x, y, z = ch_db.connect()`) (note: that function does not create/assign `date_var` currently, so you will need to fix that).  Then you can pass those three variables as arguments to `get_data()`.

Comment: HI @AlexK i fixed the date_var issue and assigned the three variables as you suggested. But it looks the problem of passing values is not fixed yet, I still get the same error.

Comment: Please spend some time and go through some Python tutorials on functions.  There is plenty of them online.  You don't call a function from that function (unless you are doing recursion).  Function calls are separate from function definitions.  And if you define a function with positional arguments, then any call to that function has to pass variables that you previously created as arguments in that function call.

Comment: Hi @AlexK, I followed your advice. I was able to use the function correctly, but at the end I realized it is not really what I am looking for. By assigning the function to a variable outside of the def function declarion, every time I run my program the function is executed. Instead, I would like to keep every function separate, while sharing data across them. For this reason, I was recommended to use Class of Functions, I made a new attempt here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67254016/use-class-to-call-functions-separately-while-saving-and-passing-values-from-one

Answer (score 0):

you could use the global keyword. I'm not a fan of this option but it works well for you here. Before pass_user = ... write on a line before (in the function) global pass_user. Same for pass_clickhouse and any variable you would need across functions.

```
global pass_user
pass_user = getpass.getpass()
print('Enter db pssw:')
global pass_clickhouse
pass_clickhouse = getpass.getpass()
```

and in get_data function just don't ask for parameters